# F# 3.0 Type Providers for science

Tags: f#, computer-science, type-providers

It seems that F# Type Providers are the leading feature of F# 3.0. My question is simple, what should I use it for? I am scientifically oriented (engineering). The only examples I have seen so far are related to web - is it the only real use of this feature?

EDIT:

1. There is a nice introduction of Type Providers together with information on when to use them and when not to use them [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/09/24/developing-f-type-providers-with-the-f-3-0-developer-preview-an-introductory-guide-and-samples.aspx).
2. A really nice example on how to implement a Vector type is here: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/09/19/f-type-providers-as-if-by-magic/

Comment: the original demo Don did for this was allways with a type-provider for chemical-elements...

Comment: But it was just a retrieval of data from the web, right? I do not think I would ever need to retrieve data from the web. That's why I ask if there is any other use aside from that.

Comment: It's not just web. You can e.g. use it for generating entities for some SQL database during compile time.

Comment: I do not need that either. Any other use? Sad that almost the only new feature in the language I love and I do not know where I could use it...

Comment: Oldrich - If you don't do data access at all, then perhaps the feature doesn't have much use to you. There are plenty of features in Frameworks / Languages that I think are cool; but have no practical use for.

Comment: Disclaimer : I haven't used it/only saw the presentation, but from what I've seen type providers allow you to hook in to the compiler/IDE and generate Types on the fly. Are you using '?' operator for dynamic property access ? You could probably move that code in to compile time and get IDE completion/compiler type checking.

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way around.  What are the hurdles that you currently face when using F# 2?  Are there particular issues that you encounter frequently?  If you describe your problems, then we might be able to tell you whether type providers could help you out.

Comment: Well, I hoped you could list standard uses of the Type Providers for different fields. As I understand it now, it is used to access statically type data. Almost every scientific program has its own data format such as vtk, hdf5 etc. Could I use Type Providers to read/write them?

Comment: @soc WTH is this question unanswered? :-)

Comment: Because nobody has an answer...